# Add/Edit record through a modal on .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have been trying to create a the ability to add/edit records through the use of a modal in .net core.

I have been trying tutorials such as 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmNtbnUfns8
https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/12723/crud-operation-modal-popup-uses-bootstrap-in-mvc

Neither of these are working for as they are as .net. The modal isnt showing up.

> ViewClients.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Evol.Models.Clients>

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Clients";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";


<div class="card">
<div class="card-header card-header-text card-header-rose">
    <div class="card-text">
        <h4 class="card-title">Clients</h4>
        <p class="card-category"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-body table-responsive">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead class="text-gray">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClientName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Actions
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ClientName)
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-link btn-sm" onclick="EditClient?@ item.ClientID"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>


                            <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn- 
                  danger btn-link btn-sm">
                                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
              </tbody>
              </table>

      </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
             <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
              <h3 class="modal-title">AddEdit Employee</h3>
           </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">


        </div>


      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

   <script>
    var EditClient = function (ClientID) {
    var url = "/Client/EditClient?ClientID=" + ClientID;
    $("#myModalBodyDiv1").load(url, function () {
        $("#myModal1").modal("show");


    })
}
```

> EditClient.cshmtl (partial view)

```
@model Evol.Models.Clients




<form id="myForm">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClientID)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClientName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })


    <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        @if (Model.ClientID > 0)
        {
        <span>Update</span>
        }
        else
        {
            <span>Save</span>
        }
    </a>

</form>
<a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-sucess btn-block">Add Client</a>




  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $("#loaderDiv").show();

        var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
        alert("Success")
        $.ajax({


            type: "POST",
            url: "/Client/ViewClients",
            data: myformdata,
            success: function () {
                $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                $("#myModal1").modal("hide");
            }
        })
    })
})
```

> ClientContoller

```
   public IActionResult EditClient(int ClientID)
    {
        Clients client = new Clients();

        if(ClientID > 0)
        {
            var user = _context.ClientTable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ClientID == clientID);
            client.ClientID = user.ClientID;
            client.ClientName = user.ClientName;
        }
        return PartialView("EditClient", client);

    }
}
```

Comment: Beacuse you have not decorated your method with [HTTPPOST] it must be decorated ortherwise the ajax will not find the moethod

Answer (score 0):

Did You Created DbContext Class In Your Project?

[CRUD Operations In ASP.NET Core Using Entity Framework Core Code First](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-asp-net-core-using-entity-framework-core-code-first/)

[EF Core DbContext Class Sample](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-dbcontext.aspx)

below code just sample for show data and edit or add data to table.

```
   [HttpGet]  
        public IActionResult AddEditCustomer(long? id)  
        {  
            CustomerViewModel model = new CustomerViewModel();  
            if (id.HasValue)  
            {  
                Customer customer = context.Set<Customer>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id.Value);  
                if (customer != null)  
                {  
                    model.Id = customer.Id;  
                    model.FirstName = customer.FirstName;  
                    model.LastName = customer.LastName;  
                    model.MobileNo = customer.MobileNo;  
                    model.Email = customer.Email;  
                }  
            }  
            return PartialView("~/Views/Customer/_AddEditCustomer.cshtml", model);  
        }  

        [HttpPost]  
        public ActionResult AddEditCustomer(long? id, CustomerViewModel model)  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                if (ModelState.IsValid)  
                {  
                    bool isNew = !id.HasValue;  
                    Customer customer = isNew ? new Customer  
                    {  
                        AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow  
                    } : context.Set<Customer>().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id.Value);  
                    customer.FirstName = model.FirstName;  
                    customer.LastName = model.LastName;  
                    customer.MobileNo = model.MobileNo;  
                    customer.Email = model.Email;  
                    customer.IPAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();  
                    customer.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;  
                    if (isNew)  
                    {  
                        context.Add(customer);  
                    }  
                    context.SaveChanges();  
                }  
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                throw ex;  
            }  
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
```

Comment: Yes, that is not the problem. Its not evening getting to that method to return the partial view

Comment: instead of partial view you can use ViewComponent in asp core mvc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are missing the HTTP Post attribute PLEASE SEE the docs here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
[HTTPPOST]
public IActionResult EditClient(int ClientID)
{
    Clients client = new Clients();

    if(ClientID > 0)
    {
        var user = _context.ClientTable.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ClientID == clientID);
        client.ClientID = user.ClientID;
        client.ClientName = user.ClientName;
    }
    return PartialView("EditClient", client);

}
}
```